# How to handle two separate responses from the server to a JQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to use AJAX to read and write some data from my server, in one operation. I don't want the write to hold up the read, so of course on the server I could read first and respond with that data, but then how do I alert the front end to an error with the write?

Front end is Javascript and JQuery, backend is PHP - or Laravel to be precise (tho I think this question is language agnostic).

My standard JQuery AJAX request:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'savedata',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { data_to_save: JSON.stringify(mydata) }, // JSON encoded data
    success: function (data_from_server)
        {
        // Update UI with data_from_server
        },
    error: function (data)
        {
        console.log('Error:', data.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

Server side (psuedocode):

```
1. Read requested data from database (using a key in the POST params)
2. Reply to front end with requested data
3. Write data_to_save to the database
4. If there was an error in saving, how to notify the frontend as response has already been sent?
```

Or I could do two separate AJAX requests on the front end, one to read, one to write, but do I just list them one after the other in the code, or do I only fire the second in the success block of the first?
Two AJAX requests also seems much more inefficient on both front and back end.

Comment: Most db writes are very fast. Do you have some long process running before you can write to db?

Comment: After you send a response you usually can't send another response, however you may be able to [broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting) something to a client through a socket. However they can be tricky to set up properly

Comment: Could you not wait until after the write to send the response?

Comment: You can send short messages in either direction through sockets, laravel is set up nicely for this,  I highly recommend checkout out the related videos on laracasts for this.

Comment: How did u go???

Answer (score 0):

Well..... You can do it with 2 methods.

**1. Splitting process.**

I means first Ask for data. If error, Show error. If success request to Write data, get response If error show error.

**2. send response after both operation**

first read data, then write data. Send your response like,

```
{
"read":{
  "status":1
},
"write":{
  "status":0,
  "error":"the error message"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, in the controller action of saving the data, use a try catch block.

**PHP File**

```
try
{
    save_data()
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    return response->json(['message' => $e->getMessage() ], 500);
}
```

500 means server error status. You can define it yourself or get it from the Exception object. Using a try catch block ensures the ajax call to know that a success/ error has occured.

**JS File**

In the error function of ajax, you can add `data` argument, and `console.log(data)`, it will catch the error from server side.

Goodluck!